# make Set<String> serializable and pass to other activity

Tags: android

I want a list object that not allow duplicate value, which `Set<String>` is what I need.

However it can't pass to other activity via bundle or extra because it's not `serializable`?

how can I achieve this ?

```
Set<String> foo = new HashSet<String>();

Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("key", foo);

startActivity(..., i);
```

**Edit**

Instead of..

```
Set<String> foo = new HashSet<String>();
```

Change to this..

```
HashSet<String> foo = new HashSet<String>();
```

Problem Solved Thank to all .

Comment: Your question is very ambigious and vague. Please update your question to be more clear and concise with what you want. Don't add more to your question as this confuses the answers and people looking to respond.

Comment: @JoxTraex okay, I will end this question

Comment: @JoxTraex oh, I can't delete it now. sorry for un-clear question

Comment: The question is still salvageable, just make it more clear what you want. And what you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

What are you talking about...

```
public class
HashSet
extends AbstractSet<E>
implements Set<E> Cloneable Serializable
```

Hash set is serializable... You need not pass in a Set, just use a HashSet **OR** if you want to STILL use a Set, as the datatype, then cast it to HashSet when its passed in the intent.

### Ref

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashSet.html

Comment: Yes, but a HashSet imeplements Set. If you really want to Set, then casting is an option.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:-

***In the activity from which you want to send data***

ArrayList userlist= new ArrayList();

Intent intent = new Intent(context, Dashboard.class);
intent.putExtra("userlist", userlist);

***The activity in which you want to get the data***

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    userlist = (ArrayList<User>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("userlist");
```

}

***The User Bean***

public class User implements Serializable {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3200348961839049924L;
/**
 * 
 */
private String name;

private String phoneNo;

private String emailId;
```

}

Comment: This isn't really answering his question. Hes asking about Using Set, not changing his DataType or how to get the data in the activity. Not sure what you mean by "bean".

Comment: @JoxTraex Oh but he can just use it like this itself. Just replace the ArrayList with HashSet and it would be okay.

Comment: He wants the Order, you can't do that with an ArrayList, HashSet is very particular about order.

Comment: Bean is nothing but simple pojo classes with simple getters and setters.